# Choose specific calendar dates in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a column of dates from MonthYear form to mm/dd/yyyy and I can do it as a string replace but it requires 157 lines of code to get all the data changed. I want to be able to take the month and year and push out the second wednesday of the month in mm/dd/yyyy form. is that possible?

I am currently using this code

```
df['Column']=df['Column'].str.replace("December2009", "12/11/2009")
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your input data frame and expected output ?

Comment: What attempts of this have you made to do this yourself?  Have you looked into the `calendar` module, that may be helpful for something like this.

Comment: Seems like [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) would work -> `df['Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column'], format='%B%Y').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a standard library tool for this, but it's easy to make your own, something like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

test_arr = ['December2009', 'August2012', 'March2015']

def replacer(d):
    # take a datestring of format %B%Y and find the second wednesday 
    dt = datetime.strptime(d, '%B%Y')
    x = 0
    # start at day 1 and increment through until conditions satisfied
    while True:
        s = dt.strftime('%A')
        if s == 'Wednesday':
            x += 1 # if a wednesday found, increment the counter
        if x == 2:
            break # when two wednesdays found then break
        dt += timedelta(days = 1)
    return dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

df = pd.DataFrame(test_arr, columns = ['a'])
df['a'].apply(replacer) # .apply() applies the given python function to each element in the df column
```

Maybe the calendar module as recommended in the other comments could make the code look nicer but I'm unfamiliar with it so it might be something you want to look into the improve the solution